# Generating a random color

Tags: grails, groovy

I would like to generate 6 digit random colors for my line charts one for each line.
right now I have a list of colors in a Map one fixed for each event line, but now the event can be dynamic and not from this list only, so I cannot do ColorMap.get(eventname) since eventname may be totally new and not in the map. I eed to generate a random color or a color from the event name for example. should I use Math.random() or is their an easier way?

How can I do that in groovy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume by 6 digit number you mean some hex code like `#ff0000` (red). Generating random codes like those is pretty straigtforward if you treat them as random 24-bit integers. That is, a random number between 0 and 2^24 - 1. Like so:

```
def randomRgbCode() {
    def rgb = new Random().nextInt(1 << 24) // A random 24-bit integer
    '#' + Integer.toString(rgb, 16).padLeft(6, '0')
}
```

The colors code that these thing generates are pretty random, but doesn't look very nice; lots of grey-ish colors insted of some vivid ones. [These are](http://jsbin.com/uvizuy/2/edit#javascript,html,live) some colors generated by that function.

More vivid colos can be achieved thinking in random [HSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) values instead of RGB, for example generating random hues, high saturation and middle lightness. If you are using these colors for a CSS style, then it's pretty easy to generate the color codes, as CSS now [supports HSL values](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/color/HSL):

```
def randomHslCode() {
    def rnd = new Random()
    def h = rnd.nextInt(360)
    int s = 65 + rnd.nextInt(35)  // Quite saturated
    def l = 50
    "hsl($h, $s%, $l%)"
}
```

[These are](http://jsbin.com/uvizuy/3/edit#javascript,html,live) some colors generated by this new function. As you can see, much more vivid.

Now, if you are not going to use the color codes in CSS styles and you *need* to generate RGB codes, then you might generate random HSL values as explained above and then transform those values into RGB. The process is [quite straightforward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Converting_to_RGB), but requires a bit more coding:

```
import static Math.abs
def floor(x) { x as int }

def randomVividRgbCode() {
    def rnd = new Random()
    def h = rnd.nextFloat()
    def s = 0.65f + rnd.nextFloat() * 0.35f // Quite saturated
    def l = 0.5f
    rgbToColorCode(*hslToRgb(h, s, l))
}

def rgbToColorCode(r, g, b) {
    def rgb = floor(r * 255) << 16 | 
              floor(g * 255) << 8  | 
              floor(b * 255)
    '#' + Integer.toString(rgb, 16).padLeft(6, '0')
}

def hslToRgb(h, s, l) {
    def c = (1 - abs(2 * l - 1)) * s // Chroma.
    def h1 = h * 6
    def x = c * (1 - abs(h1 % 2 - 1))
    def rgb = h1 < 1 ? [c, x, 0] :
              h1 < 2 ? [x, c, 0] :
              h1 < 3 ? [0, c, x] :
              h1 < 4 ? [0, x, c] :
              h1 < 5 ? [x, 0, c] :
                       [c, 0, x]
    def (r, g, b) = rgb
    def m = l - c * 0.5
    [r + m, g + m, b + m]
}
```

I hope that code is not so cryptic :). [These are](http://jsbin.com/uvizuy/4/edit#javascript,html,live) some colors generated by it.

---

Now, you may notice that some of the generated colors are quite similar, which may not be very good if you want to distinguish the lines in a chart. What you can do to avoid this is have a nice pallete of pre-defined and easily distinguishable colors (you can find a lot of them on the internet) and pick the colors from there. If you run out of colors from the pallete (maybe there is no limit to the amount of lines that can be in a chart) you may then generate a random color using some of the method described above or any other one :)

Comment: Excellent answer.  One note about using `hsl` is, if you [need to support IE 8 or lower](http://caniuse.com/css3-colors), you'll have to convert to some form of RGB.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, @OverZealous. It's really unfortunate that IE sucks so hard :(

Comment: I have implemented a bank of colors to choose from, and the above solution is the best for getting random colors once that runs out..Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific interval of values you need to pull randomly from:

```
random = new Random()
randomInt = random.nextInt((max_value)-(min_value)+1)+(min_value)
```

For closer-to-real random, you can insert a seed value inside Random(). I recommend pulling the current system timestamp.

Comment: so this generates an integer with 6 digits for color?

Comment: Well, if max_value = 999999 and min_value = 10000...that would randomly spit out 6 digit numbers between those values.

Comment: ok thanx..I will try this, but I think I should use hexadecimal numbers for colors..

Comment: "I would like to generate 6 digit numbers" Sorry, I assumed decimal, and not hex.